# Ставится ли запятая перед "что-то"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Где ставится запятая в предложении: "Но тогда почему девушку что-то беспокоило?"
И если нигде, то почему? И всегда ли перед "что" или "что-то" ставится запятая?

Comment: "И если нигде, то почему?" Такой вопрос предполагает, что отвечающий рассмотрит каждое слово в предложении и объяснит, почему запятая после него не ставится. Есть желающие ответить?

Comment: @М_Г, судя по контексту вопроса, девушка интересуется именно запятой перед "что-то". В любом случае, лично я бы ответил примерно так: "Не ставится нигде, потому что я не вижу ни одного места в этом предложении, где ее нужно ставить". Но боюсь что в этом случае уважаемые эксперты укажут на то, что мой ответ недостаточно полон.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky С тем же успехом Елизавета могла предположить, что запятая ставится перед *тогда* или перед *почему*. Вопросы "почему не?" самые неприятные.

Answer (score 1):

> Но тогда почему девушку что-то беспокоило?

Запятые не нужны.

"Что-то" — не союз, поэтому вопрос о постановке запятой перед ним не имеет смысла.

> [ЧТО-ТО](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE), чего-то, чему-то, что-то, чем-то, о чём-то; местоим. сущ. Некий предмет, некое явление и т.п.; нечто. Что-то звякнуло и упало. Он хотел сказать что-то важное. В лице её что-то приятное. В супе чего-то не хватает. Что-то продолговатое было завёрнуто в бумагу. Ей нужно было что-то ему рассказывать. Он узнал что-то новое. / Некое чувство, свойство и т.п. Что-то гордое есть в нём.

Comment: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D7%F2%EE-%F2%EE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=acomma&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=1

Comment: @slava1947, Я ожидал чего-то подобного, но не от Вас. "Не  требует запятой" означает, что не является причиной постановки запятой. А по разным другим причинам запятая может стоять перед любым словом из словаря.

Comment: Ну а зачем было писать: "Что-то -- не союз, поэтому..." Разве сами по себе союзы требуют постановки запятой?

Comment: @slava1947 Союзы — иногда, если не требуют, то обозначают место (по крайней мере мы читаем о постановке запятой перед тем или иным союзом), а в отношении местоимений так вопрос не ставится.

Comment: @slava1947 Вот пример: "Постановка запятой перед союзом КАК" (Грамота ру)

Comment: @slava1947 Все-таки я изменил формулировку под давлением Вашей критики.

Answer (score 1):

*Но тогда почему девушку что-то беспокоило?*

Как известно, в **простом неосложненном предложении знаков препинания нет**. Остается доказать, что это именно такое предложение.

*Что-то* ― **подлежащее**, выражено **неопределенным местоимением** (местоименным существительным). *Беспокоило* ― сказуемое,  *девушку* ― дополнение, *тогда* ― обстоятельства, *но* ― союз.

Это простое предложение. Здесь нет однородных или обособленных членов, нет союзов, поэтому нет и запятой.

Answer (score 0):

> > И если нигде, то почему?

Так вопрос ставить нельзя. Нигде – просто потому что нет причин для постановки запятой. Вот если запятая стоит, тогда вы вправе спросить почему.

Comment: "Нигде – просто потому что нет причин для постановки запятой" - мне кажется, что это и есть правильный ответ.